# Alternative proof that of the Uniform Boundedness Principle when $Y$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I just read an alternative proof of the Uniform Boundness Principle when $Y$ is banach space that goes like this; Suppose we have $X$ and $Y$ Banach spaces and $F \subset L(X,Y)$ such that for every $x\in X$, $\sup_{T\in F}\|Tx\|<\infty $. Then it follows that $\sup_{T\in F}\|T\|< \infty$.

> Let $B(F,Y)$ be the vector space formed by the applications $f$ defined in $F$ and that take value in $Y$, since $Y$ is a complete space this will be a complete hence a Banach space. Now define $S : X\rightarrow B(F,Y)$ as $(Sx)T=T(x), T\in F$. This will be a linear operator and using the closed graph theorem its easy to show that this will be a limited operator, because it will be a closed operator.

Now  we have that for $T \in F $ and $x\in X$ $\|Tx\|=\|(Sx)T\|\leq \|Sx\|\leq \|S\| \cdot \|x\|$ and so we get our result.

My doubt is when we make the step $\|(Sx)T\|\leq \|Sx\|$ I dont quite see why this is true , shouldnt we have that $\|(Sx)T\|\leq \|(Sx)\|\cdot \|T\|$?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I just edited to clean up formatting. In particular, in future you'll get better formatting by writing "\sup" rather than "sup" for suprema in formulae and by using "\|" rather than "||" to format norms. I also replaced some quantifiers with words to improve readability. Also, can you clarify what is meant by "applications $f$ defined in $F$..."? $F$ is not a vector space so I guess this is meant to be some function space but then it's unclear which one and with which norm

Comment: The definition of $B(F,Y)$ is very vague, which makes this seem fishy. Further this situation is not different from the situation where $Y$ is not Banach, because $F$ is bounded in $L(X,Y)$ $\iff$ it is bounded in $L(X,\overline Y)$ (the embedding of $L(X,Y)$ into $L(X,\overline Y)$ is _isometric_). Where is the proof from?

Comment: Yeah thats the definition of $B(F,Y)$ that I have also , this is from my course notes, I would share but they are in portuguese @s.harp

Comment: It is not surprising that "closed graph theorem" would imply "uniform boundedness principle".  On the other hand, some books may first do uniform boundedness, and then use that to prove closed graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not quite familiar with this concept but it looks like $||Sx||$ is really more of an operator norm, since $S$ maps to a space of operators. Hence $||Sx||=\sup_{||T||_{\text{op}}\le1}||(Sx)T||\ge ||(Sx)T||$ for all $||T||_{\text{op}}\le 1$. However, I don't see, why this should be true for all $T$ regardless of their norm.